# php display number of images uploaded by a user via path of the database

Tags: php

I have a situation here. im developing a site on which people displays their ads and each ad has some photos uploaded with it..

i need to display the number of images that has been uploaded by the user; either 1 or 2 or 3 etc.. In my database, the images are stored as path in fields namely:photo_1, photo_2, photo_3 etc till photo_10.

Then i have a folder named: /photo_principale/ in which every photos are stored.

i need to show the number of images per ads..

i dont know if im clear enough. im having a bad time with that...:(

here are my codes:

```
<?php 
$result = mysql_query("select (count(photo_1) + count(photo_2) + count(photo_3) + count(photo_4))  FROM deposer_une_annonce WHERE id = 442");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);


echo "Images uploaded by a user: " . $row;


?>
```

Comment: Why not `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM X WHERE ID=Y` ? I'm afraid your database schema has 10 "photo attributes" with null values ?

Comment: I don't think that will produce the same count @ClémentMalet

Comment: @putvande Yes, maybe, I'm not sure about OP' database schema though.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `count(*)` function to get total number of images of single user

```
SELECT count(*) FROM `deposer_une_annonce` where id=442
```

Answer (score 0):

Your table is a bit strange.

Would be better if you create a table named `images` (or ads? your question is not so clear) like this:

```
Images
------
ID Primary Key Int,
UserID int,
Path text
```

`UserID` is the ID of the user which uploads the user, `Path` is where the file is located (well, you could avoid that and use ID to identify this if you store images in format `image_ID` but whatever)

Every time an user uploads an image, create a new row in this table and stop!

Then you can do

```
SELECT count(*) FROM [table_name / or images in this case] WHERE UserID = ?
```

Comment: I cant create another table in this case because every information here are stored in the table "deposer_une_annonce". that y i need to know if i can count and echo the number of images uploaded. in my database there are other fields and 10 fields reserved for the images...